# Mailman 404 page not found

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, python, mailman

I have configured mailman following these instructions.

https://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-install/index.html

I have run into this problem

Problem:
All Mailman web pages give a 404 File not found error.
Solution:

```
Your web server has not been set up properly for handling Mailman’s CGI programs. Make sure you
have:

1. configured the web server to give permissions to ‘$prefix/cgi-bin’
2. restarted the web server properly.

Consult your web server’s documentation for instructions on how to do check these issues.
```

this is my httpd.conf file

```
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin
Alias /pipermail/ /usr/local/mailman/archives/public/
     <Directory "/usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/">
       AllowOverride None
       Options None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
     <Directory "/usr/local/mailman/archives/public/">
       Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride none
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I would love some help here.  Going on two days not being able to figure this out!

Note:  I have done what it says in the error message.

Ahh, forgot that I had started using https, and was looking in the wrong error logs.  Think I may have figured it out.  Here is the error log file.  Looks like I need to change the permissions.

```
[Thu Dec 11 11:10:05 2014] [error] [client 166.173.58.152] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Thu Dec 11 11:10:21 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Thu Dec 11 11:13:09 2014] [error] [client 173.57.131.200] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Thu Dec 11 15:23:12 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:23:16 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:24:46 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:29 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/create' failed
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:29 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] Premature end of script headers: create
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:38 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:45 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:53 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/create' failed
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:53 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] Premature end of script headers: create
[Thu Dec 11 15:38:39 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:38:44 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:42:40 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:42:44 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:44:08 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-binadmin
[Thu Dec 11 15:44:18 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:49:26 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:49:27 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] File does not exist: /var/www/html/mailman
[Thu Dec 11 15:49:31 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:52:55 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:52:57 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:58:03 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
[Thu Dec 11 15:58:04 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the problem:

```
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin
```

as evidenced by your error log entry

```
[Thu Dec 11 15:58:04 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bincreate
```

This should have a trailing `/`, i.e.:

```
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/
```

Comment: nice catch.  Any idea why im getting the below error.  All files are 755

Comment: `11 15:36:29 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/usr/local/mailman/cgi-bin/create' failed
[Thu Dec 11 15:36:29 2014] [error] [client 72.54.81.74] Premature end of script headers: create`